# How can we get vowel substring from a given string

Tags: c

I want to get all vowel substrings from the given string.
Given string is '**auiouxaeibaou**', get substrings from the given string like [**auiou**,**aei**,**aou**].

Here I tried something like this, but not getting the exact output.

```
bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

void substr(char str[], int low, int high)
{
    printf("%.*s \n\n ", high-low+1, (str+low));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    char str[] = "aeixae";

    int length = strlen(str);

    int start_index = 0, end_index = 0;

    for (int x=0; x<length; x++) {
        char c  = str[x];
        if (isVowel(c) == false) {
            end_index = x;
            substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );
            start_index = end_index + 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also try `str[] = "xxauiouxaeibaouxx"` with `printf("<%.*s>\n", ...` to stress test your algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your attempt was close. I just added the includes and made sure that the last part of the string also was printed. See the termination of the for loop and the if where you check for the vowel.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

void substr(char str[], int low, int high)
{
    printf("%.*s \n\n", high-low+1, (str+low));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    char str[] = "aeixae";

    int length = strlen(str);

    int start_index = 0, end_index = 0;

    for (int x=0; x<=length; x++) {
        if (x == length || !isVowel(str[x])) {
            end_index = x;
            substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );
            start_index = end_index + 1;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the output:

```
gcc main.c && ./a.out 
aei 

ae
```

Comment: @KamilCuk `str[length]` is `null` terminator. Not out of bound.

Comment: I agree with @kiranBiradar - but rewrote the if statement. the isVowel function will not be called if x == length

Comment: Code erroneously prints an empty sub-string when `str[]` begins with a non-vowel.

Comment: Code erroneously prints an empty sub-string when `str[]` ends with a non-vowel.

Comment: @Jörg Beyer logic needs some changes. consider 'aeixaexx' string. it will get failed.

Answer (score 2):

1. Nice program. Remember to use `size_t` as the proper type returned by `strlen()`.
2. Well, if you want input to be `auiouxaeibaou`, you need to insert it at `char str[] = "aeixae";`
3. Great `substr` function!
4. You need to remember about the last substr from the string - when `x` reaches `lenth`, there is still one substring

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

void substr(char str[], int low, int high)
{
    printf("%.*s\n", high-low+1, (str+low));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

    // ch-ch-ch-changes   
    char str[] = "auiouxaeibaou";

    int length = strlen(str);

    int start_index = 0, end_index = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++) {
        char c  = str[x];
        if (isVowel(c) == false) {
            end_index = x;
            substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );
            start_index = end_index + 1;
        }
    }

    // ch-ch-ch-changes
    end_index = length;
    substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Plenty of good answers already. Consider using `strspn` and `strnspn`, especially as they handle the null terminator reasonably well.

Comment: Code has same 2 problems: as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409302/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

> but not getting the exact output.

why you don't have the expected result :

- you miss the last sequence of vowel, to have it just replace `for (int x=0; x<length; x++)` by `for (int x=0; x<=length; x++)` because the null character is not a vowel (that does not produce illegal access)
- when you have several consecutive non vowel you call anyway substr, to avoid that you need to memorize if had or not previously a vowel

The modifications gives that (I changed the input string) :

```
bool isVowel(char c) {
    return (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u');
}

void substr(char str[], int low, int high)
{
    printf("%.*s \n\n ", high-low+1, (str+low));
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  char str[] = "aeixaewwii";

  int length = strlen(str);

  int start_index = 0, end_index = 0;
  bool wasVowel = false;

  for (int x=0; x<=length; x++) {
    char c  = str[x];
    if (isVowel(c) == false){
      end_index = x;
      if (wasVowel)
        substr(str, start_index, end_index - 1 );
      start_index = end_index + 1;
      wasVowel = false;
    }
    else
      wasVowel = true;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

BTW : 'y' is a vowel for me, you missed it in *isVowel()*

Comment: Good that this code does not exhibit the 2 problems found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409246/2410359) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409302/2410359) answers.

Comment: @chux what are the 2 additional problems found in the answers you give ? I do not see them.

Comment: @chux  And I just see your answer where you do not at all speak about the problems in the initial code, is that a joke ?

Comment: The 2 other linked answers [incorrectly report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408929/how-can-we-get-vowel-substring-from-a-given-string/54409319?noredirect=1#comment95652047_54408929)  empty subsets when `char str[]` begin/ends with a non-vowel.  That comment did need a better failing test cast to show the weakness.

Comment: @chux my answer speaks about that in the second dot !

Comment: The comments of the 2 answers are due to not functioning correct.  I did not comment about their lack of information.  Yes, this answer does well [address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408929/how-can-we-get-vowel-substring-from-a-given-string/54410115?noredirect=1#comment95653341_54409319) an issue as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408929/how-can-we-get-vowel-substring-from-a-given-string/54410115?noredirect=1#comment95637693_54409319) and for that was UVed.  IMO OP selected an incorrect answer.  This one is correct (AFAICT) and does explain various OP's mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

For fun, here is a simple way to do it without substrings, just print vowels as they come and add newlines the first time you hit a consonant.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int isVowel(char c){
    if(c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u'){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return -1;
    }
}

int main()
{       
   char my_str[] = "auiouxxxxxxaeibaou";

   int todo_newline = 1; // prevent consecutive newlines

   for(int i = 0; my_str[i] != '\0'; i++){
       if(isVowel(my_str[i]) == 1){
           printf("%c", my_str[i]);
           todo_newline = 1; 
       }
       else{
           if(todo_newline == 1){ // print one newline
               printf("%c", '\n');
               todo_newline = -1; // don't print consecutive newlines
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Suggest `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(my_str); i++){` to `for(int i = 0; my_str[i] != '\0'; i++){` to avoid very _slow_ code with long strings when `strlen()` not optimized out.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

[`strspn()`](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strspn), [`strcspn()`](https://clc-wiki.net/wiki/strcspn) are the best tools here.  [@Gem Taylor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54408929/how-can-we-get-vowel-substring-from-a-given-string/54410115#comment95631042_54409246)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[] = "aeixae";
  const char *s = str;
  while (*(s += strcspn(s, "aeiou")) != '\0') { // skip letters that are not aeiou
    size_t len = strspn(s, "aeiou");            // find length made up of aeiou
    printf("<%.*s>\n", (int) len, s);           // print sub string
    s += len;
  }
}
```

Output

```
<aei>
<ae>
```

Comment: That answer does not exhibit *at all* why the initial code doesn't work, how can you critic the other answers about that in these conditions ? This is surreal ^^

Comment: @bruno This answer describes an alternative approach.  Other answers well explain OP's code shortcomings yet do not provide a simple complete solution.

Comment: @chux so when the answer doesn't come from you you critic it saying "it doesn't explain the problem(s)" *including when the answer does*, and when it is from you the answer is free to say everything without having to explain the problem(s). To resume "do what I say, do not do what I do", interesting ...

Comment: @bruno None of my comments here critiqued about "it doesn't explain the problem(s)" .  My comments did point out where an answer was functionally incorrect.